# Angular ng-disabled is not working

Tags: angularjs

Why is my button not enabling and disabling with this code:

```
<form name="formSendEmail" ng-submit="sendEmailAction();">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label label-muted" for="visitorEmailForSendEmail">Visitor E-mail</label>
        <input type="email" value="{{visitorDetail2.EmailAddress}}" id="visitorEmailForSendEmail" name="visitorEmailForSendEmail" class="form-control" ng-required="true" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send E-mail" ng-disabled="formSendEmail.$invalid" />
</form>
```

Just above that code I have another form with a name of `formCreateItinerary` and I change my `ng-disabled` to point to that form; the enabling and disabling of the button works. 
I have used this code too:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send E-mail" ng-disabled="visitorEmailForSendEmail == undefined || visitorEmailForSendEmail == ''" />
```

With this code, the button is disabled and does not enable. Can you help?

Comment: ng-disabled works on a boolean value

Comment: Yes I know. if my input is valid it should return true and if not then false.

Comment: You mean `ng-disabled="formSendEmail.$invalid"` is working but `ng-disabled="visitorEmailForSendEmail == undefined || visitorEmailForSendEmail == ''"` does not working. Correct?

Comment: ng-disabled="visitorEmailForSendEmail == undefined || visitorEmailForSendEmail == ''" makes the button disabled even though the input element is valid or the form is valid.

Comment: And I think my `required` part is working 'cause when I submit and there is no value in the input field, a tool tip comes out saying that that input is required to be filled.

Comment: Use $scope.$apply() Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797737/ng-disabled-not-evaluating-after-data-change

Comment: I don't get it. How can $scope.$apply() work for me? If I point my ng-disabled to another form which is just right on top of the form with issue, the button works as expected.

Comment: @stackquestions you need `ng-model`. Consider changing `value="{{visitorDetail2.EmailAddress}}"` to `ng-model="visitorDetail2.EmailAddress"` or something similar

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing the `value="{{visitorDetail2.EmailAddress}}"`  to `ng-model="visitorDetail2.EmailAddress"`

```
<input type="email" ng-model="emailAddress" ng-change="validateEmail(emailAddress)" id="visitorEmailForSendEmail" name="visitorEmailForSendEmail" class="form-control" ng-required="true" />
<button ng-disabled="disableButton">button</button>

 $scope.validateEmail=function(email) {
       if(!validateEmail(email)){
            $scope.disableButton=true;
               }else{
            $scope.disableButton=false;
        }

  }

 function validateEmail(email) {
     var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
  }
```